# Facets not working properly plotly express

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.histogram(df, nbins = 5, x = "numerical_col", color = "cat_1", animation_frame="date",
                  range_x=["10000","500000"], facet_col="cat_2")

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=25, r=25, t=20, b=20))

fig.show()
```

How can I fix the output? I would like multiple subplots based on cat_2 where the hue is cat_1.

[image: this is how my output looks like]

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data,  so I've simulated it based on code you are using to generate figure
- I have encountered one issue **range_x** does not work, it impacts *y-axis* as well.  Otherwise approach fully works.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# data not provided.... simulate some
DAYS = 5
ROWS = DAYS * 2000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_d": np.repeat(pd.date_range("1-Jan-2021", periods=DAYS), ROWS // DAYS),
        "numerical_col": np.random.uniform(10000, 500000, ROWS),
        "cat_1": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), ROWS),
        "cat_2": np.random.choice(list("UVWXYZ"), ROWS),
    }
)
# animation frame has to be a string not a date...
df["date"] = df["date_d"].dt.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")
# always best to provide pre-sorted data to plotly
df = df.sort_values(["date", "cat_1", "cat_2"])
fig = px.histogram(
    df,
    nbins=5,
    x="numerical_col",
    color="cat_1",
    animation_frame="date",
    # range_x=[10000, 500000],
    facet_col="cat_2",
)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=25, r=25, t=20, b=20))
```

[image]

Comment: I have around 40 different categories in my cat_2 is this the reason for it not splitting up the way its supposed to be? I did remove range but the output is still the same. My guess is having around 40-45 different categories might be a reason?

Comment: 40 figures in one row is excessive. If you screen is 1600 wide that’s only 40 pixels per row !